# How to remove directory and show only file name in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

im trying to make only the file name show up using filedialog

here's the example :

```
import tkinter as tk
import pygame
from tkinter import filedialog

root = tk.Tk()

controls_frame = tk.Frame(root)
controls_frame.pack()

def add_name():
    name = filedialog.askopenfile()
    names.insert(filedialog.END,name)

names = tk.Listbox(root,bg="black",fg="red",width=60,height=6)
names.pack(pady=0,side='bottom')

add_name_btn = tk.Button(controls_frame , text='add name' , command=add_name)
add_name_btn.grid(column=3,row=0,padx=20) 

root.mainloop()
```

it shows the full directory to the file, which i dont want.
how do i remove the directory that it shows on box?

Comment: Read up on all of the features in python's [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)

Comment: Though keep in mind, I think you need `askopenfilename()`, `askopenfile()` is used for opening the file itself.

Answer (score 0):

The module `os` can help with this:

```
import os

    def add_name():
        name = os.path.basename(str(filedialog.askopenfile()))
        name = name.replace("' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>", "")
        names.insert(filedialog.END,name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.
I found this solution on another post.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import filedialog
def filename123():
    global filename1, nopath1
    filename1 = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    nopath1 = filename1.split("/")[len(filename1.split("/"))-1]
filename123()
```